# What does it mean when the $ symbol is prefixed to a word in Neo4j Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In neo4j examples they use the `$` symbol before words like in the example below on line `2`.

```
MATCH (excluded:Ingredient)
WHERE excluded.name in $excludedIngredients
WITH collect(excluded) as excluded
MATCH (r:Recipe)
WHERE NONE(i in excluded WHERE (r)-[:INCLUDES]->(i))
RETURN r
```

What does this mean and why do they do it.  It looks like a list that is predefined or something but I dont know where it may be predefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are parameters to the query, which are predefined and passed alongside the query. Here's the [parameter documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) which should answer any additional questions on usage.

Comment: Well, that makes sense now thank you @InverseFalcon